# loop sql query in a bash script

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, loops, sqlplus

I need to loop a oracle sqlplus query using bash.

my scenario is like this. I have a set of names in a text file and i need to find out details of that names using a sqlplus query.

textfile.txt content:

```
john
robert
samuel
chris
```

bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
/opt/oracle/bin/sqlplus -s user@db/password @query.sql $line
done < /tmp/textfile.txt
```

sql query: query.sql

```
set verify off
set heading off
select customerid from customers where customername like '%&1%';
exit
```

problem is when I run the script I get errors like

> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning
>   "robert..." - rest of line ignored.

can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: usually it's better to perform one big query and avoid loops over sql

Comment: Indeed.  It looks like the OP is trying to re-invent a stored procedure kept in a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this all the time is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat textfile.txt |while read Name
do
sqlplus -s userid/password@db_name > output.log <<EOF
set verify off 
set heading off 
select customerid from customers where customername like '%${Name}%'
/
exit
EOF
```

Bash will auto magically expand ${Name} for each line and place it into the sql command before sending it into sqlplus

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `set define on` ? Is your wildcard `&` ? You could check `glogin.sql` to know.

And yes, establishing `n` connections to pass `n` queries is probably not a good solution. Maybe it's faster for you to develop and you will do that one time, but if not, you should maybe think of crafting a procedure.